# Reformatting a Table using Power Pivot or VBA or excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, powerpivot

I have a table with over 35000 rows that i need to reformat. I get this type of file every 2 days and would like to know if there is a faster and easier way to reformat the data.
[Original File]
[image]

[Intended Format]
[image]

I need to move the data from columns L to Q in columns J and K ( type in column J and value in column K). I am using Excel 2016

I have tried to use pivot table but it has not worked.

Comment: If you're calling out specific columns then including the column headers in your screenshots is useful...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: tested and fixed a few bugs...

This works for me:

```vb
Sub reformat()

    Dim rngDup As String, arrStack As Variant, rw As Range, rwOut As Range, i As Long, rng As Range
    
    rngDup = "A1:H1"  'copy this for each output row (note range is *relative* to the row)
    
    'pieces of input row to copy, along with labels
    arrStack = Array("I1:K1", "Earnings" , _
                     "L1:M1", "Deductions", _
                     "N1:O1", "Emp. Taxes", _
                     "P1:Q1", "Emp. Deductions")
    
    Set rw = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Data").Rows(2)          'start of input data
    Set rwOut = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Reformatted").Rows(2) 'start of reformatted data
    
    Application.Screenupdating = False
    Do While Application.CountA(rw.Range(rngDup)) > 0       'while have input data...
        For i = LBound(arrStack) To UBound(arrStack) Step 2 'loop ranges to check
            Set rng = rw.Range(arrStack(i))
            If Application.CountA(rng) > 0 Then             'something to copy?
                rw.Range(rngDup).Copy rwOut.Cells(1)
                rwOut.Range("I1").Value = arrStack(i + 1)   'label
                rng.Copy rwOut.Range("J1")                  'copy data
                Set rwOut = rwOut.Offset(1)                 'next paste row
            End If
        Next i
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1)                               'next input row
    Loop
End Sub
```